# Python Scatter Plot using CSV

Tags: python, scatter-plot

Using Python: I am trying to make a scatter plot using .csv dataframes that visualizes FIM admission and discharge scores. I am able to make a scatter plot but am struggling to...

Make male scatter points: Blue, circle markers ("."), size 100, label "Male (N=)"

Make female scatter points: Red, plus markers ("+"), size 100, label "Female (N=)"

Y = X line: Black, dashed line style ("--"), x limits and y limits are [0, 140]
My graph is supposed to read into my 'RIC' column but make a different graph for each instance within the column (for example 'repILE')

This is what it should look like:
[image]

I have included the code I have so far:

```
patient_data_df.plot.scatter(x='Admission Total FIM Score', y= 'Discharge Total FIM Score', s=50, marker= "X", color= "green")

plt.title("FIM Scatter Plot:<RIC> (N=<total>)<RIC> (N=<total>)")

#plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use matplotlib instead pandas plot

Here example code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame([[1.1, 4.2, 'Male'], [1.2, 3.3, 'Male'], [2.3, 3.2, 'Male'], [1.4, 7.1, 'Male'], [1.3, 3.2, 'Female'], [2.3, 2.2, 'Female'], [4.2, 1.8, 'Female']], columns=['Admission Total FIM Score', 'Discharge Total FIM Score', 'Sex'])

x_name = 'Admission Total FIM Score'
y_name = 'Discharge Total FIM Score'

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.plot([0, 5], [0, 5], 'k--', label='No Change')
plt.plot(data[data.Sex == 'Female'][x_name], data[data.Sex == 'Female'][y_name], 'r+', label='Female (N=%i)' % len(data[data.Sex == 'Female']))
plt.plot(data[data.Sex == 'Male'][x_name], data[data.Sex == 'Male'][y_name], 'b.', label='Male (N=%i)' % len(data[data.Sex == 'Male']))
plt.title('RepILE (N=%i)' % len(data))
plt.xlabel(x_name)
plt.ylabel(y_name)
plt.legend();
```

Output graph:

[image]